# Jenkins pipeline groovy string compare

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

When I use Jenkins pipeline through with Docker, I want to compare string value with Groovy script, but the compare result was wrong, the follow script is my groovy script and the output result:

Is there anyone can tell me how resolve this problem?

```
String runningContainerId = sh(script: "docker ps --filter=\"name=${appEnv}-${env.JOB_NAME}-${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\" -q | xargs", returnStdout: true)
//def runningImageId = sh(script: "docker images | grep ${appEnv}-${env.JOB_NAME}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 ", returnStdout: true)

println 'current container:' + runningContainerId
//println runningImageId
try{
def ret = sh(script: "docker ps --filter=\"name=${appEnv}-${env.JOB_NAME}\" -q | xargs", returnStdout: true)
def splitStr = ret.tokenize(" ")
println 'splitStr=>' + splitStr
String containerId = runningContainerId
println 'containerId=>' + containerId

for( String str in splitStr) {
    print str == containerId
    print 'str=>' + str
     if ( str == containerId) {
        print 'same string:' + str 
     } else {
        print 'different string:' + str
     }
}
```

Jenkins output result is:

```
splitStr=>[8abe81071b7f, 40e2292d5099, 4136bbdf9cc5]
[Pipeline] echo
containerId=>8abe81071b7f

[Pipeline] echo
false
[Pipeline] echo
str=>8abe81071b7f
[Pipeline] echo
different string:8abe81071b7f
[Pipeline] echo
false
[Pipeline] echo
str=>40e2292d5099
[Pipeline] echo
different string:40e2292d5099
[Pipeline] echo
false
[Pipeline] echo
str=>4136bbdf9cc5

[Pipeline] echo
different string:4136bbdf9cc5
```

Comment: check if there are spaces on the end of the string

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!
With your suggestion I had solve my problem.

Comment: @herryliq can you post that and accept it as an answer?